# JMeter Groovy re execute a Sampler X times under condition

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223, retry-logic

I want to re execute a Sampler for 5 times or until a certain variable has the value "true", Is there any method in Groovy or do I have to do something in JMeter?

Answer (score 2):

Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as Sampler's PostProcessor to retry Sampler in case variable condition is true

Also update and check retryCount:

```
if (vars.getObject("retryCount") < 5 && "true".equals(vars.get("condition"))) {
   retryCountNow = vars.getObject("retryCount") + 1;
   vars.putObject("retryCount", retryCountNow);
   ctx.getCurrentSampler().sample(null);
}
```

retryCount can be insert in JSR223 PreProcessor of request:

```
vars.putObject("retryCount",0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) with condition like

```
${__javaScript(("${certain variable}" != "true" && ${counter} < 5),)}
```

Where `counter` is the reference name of the [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) test element.

Put the request you want to re-execute as a child of the While Controller and it will be something you're looking for

Comment: Shouldn't we use __groovy/__jexl3 over __javascript?